# Jquery Replace while Looping LI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="intro"><h2 class="heading">Info</h2>
    <ul class="cons" style="text-align: left;">
       <li>Song : Oviman</li>
       <li>Drama : Best Friend 3</li>
       <li>Vocal, Tune &amp; Lyrics : Tanveer Evan</li>
       <li>Music Composition : Piran Khan</li>
       <li>Director : Probir Roy Chowdhuy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Trying to make every this after ':' a link. like 'Best Friend 3' is a hole link. but it creates separate links for each words. And how to loop jQuery?

```
$('div.intro li').html($('div.intro li').html().replace(/((:|)[^\s]+[\w])/g, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'));
```

Comment: sry about that, its my first time. didn't know the rules.

Comment: no worries - it's because I answered your "how to loop" question, then realised that wasn't really what you wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips for you:
`$('selector').each()` <- looping through
`string.split(' : ')` <- easily splitting by known separator, then you can use .join to get them together again after performing some action

After some thinking (3min), it should be sth like that:

```
$("div.intro li").each(
  (idx, el) => {
    const splitted = el.innerText.split(" : ")
    el.innerHTML = [splitted[0], `<a>${splitted[1]}</a>`].join(" : ")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple reprenstation.

```
$(".cons li").each((index, item) => {
       var str = $(item).text();
       var replacedStr = str.replace(/((:|)[^\s]+[\w])/g, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
       $(item).html(replacedStr);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to loop jQuery

You *can* loop through using

```
$('div.intro li').each(function(i, e) { $(e).html($(e).html().replace(...)) });
```

but you could also take advantage of the [overload for html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) which does this for you:

```
$('div.intro li').html(function(i, html) { return html.replace(...) });
```

> how to convert all text into a single link instead of separate links, after the `:`

That's a case of updating your regex

```
/^(.*)\:(.*)/g
```

then update with `$1` and `$2` accordingly, giving:

```js
$('div.intro li').html(function (i, html) { 
    return html.replace(/^(.*)\:(.*)/g, '$1 : <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro"><h2 class="heading">Info</h2>
    <ul class="cons" style="text-align: left;">
       <li>Song : Oviman</li>
       <li>Drama : Best Friend 3</li>
       <li>Vocal, Tune &amp; Lyrics : Tanveer Evan</li>
       <li>Music Composition : Piran Khan</li>
       <li>Director : Probir Roy Chowdhuy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
/(: ?)((.*))/g
```

Matching every char after a colon and an optional whitespace.

Code:

```js
        $(".cons li").each(function(oLi){
        var str = $(this).html();
        str = str.replace(/(: ?)((.*))/g, '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
        $(this).html(str);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro"><h2 class="heading">Info</h2>
    <ul class="cons" style="text-align: left;">
       <li>Song : Oviman</li>
       <li>Drama : Best Friend 3</li>
       <li>Vocal, Tune &amp; Lyrics : Tanveer Evan</li>
       <li>Music Composition : Piran Khan</li>
       <li>Director : Probir Roy Chowdhuy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```